# Customize TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText

Tags: android, material-design, android-textinputlayout

Google provides material guidelines for [Text fields component](https://material.io/design/components/text-fields.html#filled-text-field). Could anyone help me how I can customize TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText available out of 'com.android.support:design' library in order to accomplish the [same visual effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EBIY.png)? In my project, I've been using min SDK version 16. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your layout

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_layout_email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gray_background"
        android:hint="@string/registration_email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**@drawable/gray_background**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#BDBDBD" />
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

**Explanation**

The following line makes the gray background you want to achieve as in the picture.

```
android:background="@drawable/gray_background"
```

This is the hint for the user (Label in your photo), by using this the user will know what he needs to type in. In my case, I am asking for the user's email.

```
// Since @string/registration_email = "Email"
android:hint="@string/registration_email"
```

Here you put the type of text the user will type. In my case, it will be a format of email adress. Possible options are: textPassword, textPersonName, textMultiLine...

```
android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
```

**Color**

In your photo when the field is active it becames purple, this is the default accent color of your application that is located in --> res/values/styles.xml.

**styles.xml**

```
<!-- 1. Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- 1.1. Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style
```

**Error Wrong Message**

If you want to display an error message if the user types in something wrong you can achieve by doing so.

In this case I have a field where the user types in the name of his channel. It'll give a WARNING if the user leaves it blank, or in case he types in more than 60 characteres.

```
private TextInputEditText mChannelName;
private TextInputLayout mChannelNameLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_searchable);

    mChannelName = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_channel_name);
    mChannelNameLayout = findViewById(R.id.input_layout_channel_name);

    setupEditTextFeatures();
}

/**
 * 1) Set the error messages to the edit texts;
 * 2) Set the maximum length for the fields.
 */
private void setupEditTextFeatures() {

// 1) Error message if the user leave Channel Name field empty;
mChannelName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (mChannelName.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            mChannelNameLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);
            mChannelNameLayout.setError(getString(R.string.msg_fill_in_channel_name_please));
        } else {
            mChannelNameLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
});

// 2) Set Channel Name Field's maximum length to 60 characters;
mChannelNameLayout.setCounterEnabled(true);
mChannelNameLayout.setCounterMaxLength(60);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. Unfortunately, your solution is different and doesn't look as well as google's input. In this example, the drawable gray_background applies to TextInputLayout and it means the background will be lower than the line which is under the typed text at TextInputEditText and the error message will be covered by background color as well.

Comment: You are right, I didn't attempt to this detail. I moved the background for the edittext and put some height for it. It'll still not be exactly the way you want but it'll me more similar.

Comment: The background should be over layout and edit text controls but don't cover the section with an error message. I'd found the [control](https://github.com/HITGIF/TextFieldBoxes) which is similar to what I need.